# X11 forwarding firefox not working, and no errors

Tags: x11, firefox, optimus

I am trying to run firefox over X11 and can't get it to work. I am running OpenSuse 42.3, and have an optimus graphics card with bumblebeed installed.

When I try

`firefox` or `firefox --no-remote` or `firefox-no-remote -no-xshm` there is no output on the console 
(just goes to the next line after enter and just sits there), and no screen comes up. Same with `glxgears`.

`kleopatra`, `xterm`, `xev` works over ssh. And when I connect to the same server from another computer, firefox works too...

On remote, glxinfo also doesn't output much...

```
[sachi@hostname ~]$ glxinfo 
name of display: localhost:10.0
```

So I think this might have to do with OpenGL/graphix. How do I debug?

I am starting `ssh -Y <host>` and on remote the `$DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`.

With verbose log on ssh connection, I don't see any immediate problems either..

---

Output of `glxgears` on the local X11 server,

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)  (0x1616)
    Version: 17.0.5
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 3072MB
    Unified memory: yes
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.5
    Max compat profile version: 3.0
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, 
    GL_ARB_compute_shader, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
    GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, 
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_clock, GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision, 
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, GL_ARB_texture_barrier, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, 
    GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_cull_distance, 
    GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_clock, GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision, 
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, 
    GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, 
    GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 17.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_buffer_storage, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance, 
    GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, GL_EXT_copy_image, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers, GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, 
    GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_geometry_point_size, 
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, GL_EXT_robustness, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks, GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, 
    GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size, GL_EXT_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_buffer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rg, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, 
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, 
    GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness, 
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_NV_draw_buffers, 
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_image_formats, GL_NV_read_buffer, 
    GL_NV_read_depth, GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_sync, 
    GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_copy_image, GL_OES_depth24, 
    GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
    GL_OES_geometry_point_size, GL_OES_geometry_shader, 
    GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_gpu_shader5, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box, 
    GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading, GL_OES_sample_variables, 
    GL_OES_shader_image_atomic, GL_OES_shader_io_blocks, 
    GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation, GL_OES_standard_derivatives, 
    GL_OES_stencil8, GL_OES_surfaceless_context, 
    GL_OES_tessellation_point_size, GL_OES_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_border_clamp, GL_OES_texture_buffer, 
    GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_texture_stencil8, GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array, 
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float, 
    GL_OES_viewport_array

40 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x022 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0be 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0bf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0c5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0c7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0c8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0c9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ca 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0cb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0cc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0cd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ce 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0cf 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0d8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0d9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0da 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0db 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0dc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0dd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0de 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0df 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0e0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0e1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x07c 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

64 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x07d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x081  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x087 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x088 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x089 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08b  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x08d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x08f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x091  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x092  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x093  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x094  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x099 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a1  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ab  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ac  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ad 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0af 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b1  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b2  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b3  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b4  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ba 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0bb 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0bc 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
```

Comment: Can you run other programs such as `xterm`, `xev`, `glxgears`  remotely? Did you try with `ssh -X` ?

Comment: `xterm`, `xev` works. not `glxgears`. Same with `-X`

Comment: Edited the question with those info :) thx @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: Perhaps give output of `glxinfo` and `xdpyinfo` and look into the log of the *local* X11 server (the one driving your screen)

Comment: Added, nothing much on remote with `glxgears`. Though `xdpyinfo` outputs a lot of stuff

Comment: I used to try to do access a remote server's firefox, and the main issue I hit was it was so incredibly slow to load (what you see is a function of the remote location's upload speed limit) and even slower to operate that I gave it up as useless. I can't remember how long it took firefox to actually appear, but it was in the minutes I believe, there's something about it's interface that meant there was a ton of data to upload over a relatively slow connection, and even the slightest movement would force a full screen repaint. This isn't necessarily your issue unless a time out happening.

Comment: @Lizardx, Not really, coz it works when I connect through a different server from NX. :/

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, uh! just saw you asked for the local output. Added that to the question. Thx!